# homeomorphism as a result of other homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, continuity

If
$$B = \bigcup_{R>0} B_R$$
and all the identities
$$\operatorname{id}_R : (B_R,d_1) \rightarrow (B_R,d_2)$$
for $R>0$ are homeomorphisms, then is 
$$ \operatorname{id} : (B,d_1) \rightarrow (B,d_2) $$
a homeomorphism?

Comment: What are $B$ and the $B_R$?

Comment: $(X, \rho)$ is a metric space.
$$B_R(X) := \{ A \in B(X)  \mid  A\subset B(p,R) \},$$ 
where $B(p,R)=\{x\mid \rho(x,p)\le R\}$
$$B(X) :=\{A \subseteq X \mid A \neq \emptyset , A = \overline{A}, A \text{ is bounded} \}.$$
$$B:= B(X), B_R := B_R(X)$$

Comment: And if $\operatorname{id}$ resp. $\operatorname{id}_R$ denotes the identity, note that the identity of a topological space is trivially a homeomorphism. If $\operatorname{id}_{(R)}$ denotes something other than the pertinent identity map, that is bad notation.

Comment: I just do not understand the answer in this question:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338946/existence-of-a-bounded-ball/1339762?noredirect=1#comment2724926_1339762

Comment: @DanielFischer I forgot to mention that these are the same spaces with different metrics. Is it ok now?

Comment: Aha. We have [potentially] different topologies on the domain and the codomain. The point is that every $B_R(X)$ is open in $B(X)$ (with respect to both metrics). If we have topological spaces $S,T$, and a family $\{ U_\iota : \iota \in I\}$ of open sets covering $S$, then $f\colon S \to T$ is continuous if and only if $f\lvert_{U_\iota}$ is continuous for all $\iota \in I$.

Comment: $d_1$ and $d_2$ induce the same topology and each restriction of $id$ to $B_R$ coincides with $id_R$.

Comment: Sorry, a slight correction: It is not necessarily true that every $B_R(X)$ is open with the definition of the other question. But if $R_1 < R_2$ then $B_{R_1}(X)$ is contained in the interior of $B_{R_2}(X)$. So the interiors of the $B_R(X)$ cover the space, and basically the same argument applies.